# Tableau JS Api Filter does not accept variable

Tags: javascript, string, variables, tableau-api

I am writing some code, that is supposed to automatically filter a Tableau workbook, based on the values of an array.

The function is called through:

```
showOnly2('Disponent',filterString);
```

'Disponent' is hard coded, filterString is an array of this format:

```
['201','202','203','204','205','206','207','208','209']
```

In the following block of code:

```
function showOnly2(filterName, values) {
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = values;
    sheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
    if(sheet.getSheetType() === 'worksheet') {
        sheet.applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');
    } else {
        worksheetArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
        for(var i = 0; i < worksheetArray.length; i++) {
            worksheetArray[i].applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');  
        }
    }
}
```

The `worksheetArray[i].applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');` part does not work when called with the variable "values".

However, if I hard-code the value of the array into the formula:

`worksheetArray[i].applyFilterAsync(filterName, ['201','202','203','204','205','206','207','208','209'] , 'REPLACE');`

it works like a charm...Unfortunately I cannot hard-code it, as the numbers in the array (the filter values I want to set), change over time.

Does anybody have an idea, why the variable version does not work?

(I also checked for scope issues, by implementing `document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = values;`
within the function, just to doublecheck that the array value is read properly.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is straight forward.

The API expectes an array-object not a string (although when displayed as a string both look the same).

Hence, the following code worked flawlessly:

```
var filterArray = [];
for(var i = 201; i < 300; i++) {
    filterArray.push(i);
}
```